# VBA PowerPoint create all type of shapes

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am developing some functions in vba for powerpoint. Now to test my solution I need powerpoint slides that have all shape types on a slide.

Some of them listet here are easy to create:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/Ff744590.aspx

But others such as type =msoOLEControlObject or =msoEmbeddedOLEObject or =msoplaceholder I have no idea how to create. But I need all different shape.types.

Any idea how to automatically create them?

I have tried to do it with this:

```
        Sub CreateShapeType()
        Dim slnr

        slnr = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideNumber
        Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(slnr)
        myDocument.Shapes.AddShape Type:=msoOLEControlObject, _
            left:=100, top:=50, Width:=100, Height:=200

        End Sub
```

Even though something does get created - when I control the shapes they not have the type "msoOLEControlObject".

An automated creation with a loop would be perfect. See this example (it works, but only for all autoshapes):

```
        Sub CreateAutoshapes()
          Dim i As Integer
          Dim slnr, t As Integer
          Dim shp As Shape

          slnr = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideNumber
          t = 10
          For i = 1 To 137
            Set shp = ActivePresentation.Slides(slnr).Shapes.AddShape(i, 100, t, 60, 60)
            shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = i
            t = t + 70
          Next
          ' skip 138 - not supported
          If CInt(Application.Version) >= 12 Then
            For i = 139 To 183
              Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(i, 100, t, 60, 60)
              shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = i
              t = t + 70
            Next
          End If
        End Sub
```

Any idea how to create all the different types at all?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are specific methods available for each of the shape types. AddShape is specific to AutoShapes.

Look at the other methods like AddOLEObject, AddPlaceholder, AddPicture, AddTable, AddSmartArt etc to add the other shape types.